# Setting up external libraries in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker

I'm currently setting up an external library (zlib) in Visual Studio. It's got a bin folder that has a .dll file, an include folder that has header files to include in my program, a lib folder that has .lib files, and a few other files that I'm not sure are relevant to this process. What steps should I take to be able to use this library in my program? I've done research on this already but if I'm not doing this right, please let me know.

First I went into project properies, went over to C/C++, and added the main directory of the library (containing the aforementioned subfolders) to the Additional Include Directories.

Then I went over to the Linker, and attempted to add the .lib directory under "Additional Dependencies" but it looked like a free-form text entry field and not a place where I can actually select a folder or a file so I wasn't sure what to do there so I skipped it.

Lastly, I went ahead and did an #include of the main header file of the library using its full path.

Is this all I have to do for the library to be ready for use? And is it required for the library directory to be inside my main program's directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include` the relevant header file(s) in your source code.

Put the *include* folder in `Additional Include Directories`

-- or --

Use the full path to the header file(s) in your `#includes`s.  Use a relative path if you can.

Add the full path to each of the individual `.lib` **files** as linker `Additional Dependencies`.  Again, you can use a relative path here and that is obviously preferable.

Copy the `.dll` file to the folders where your executable gets built (i.e. `Debug` and `Release`).  You can automate this in **Build Events -> Post Build Event**.

Then, if you get any error messages when you try to build, post them back to your question (verbatim, please) and maybe we can help you.

Comment: That worked! Why is that I don't have to do anything with the .lib or .dll files in the first method?

Comment: You do.  `-- or --` just applies to the `#include`(s).  Care to vote me up (optional) and accept my answer (as expected here)?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah I understand! Thank you so much! I upvoted you as well but my reputation isn't high enough for it to show.

Comment: Ah, OK.  No worries, maybe it will show up later.  Enjoy the site.

Comment: Thank you! I am actually having a problem right now (it just appeared). In my functions, it doesn't know what "zipper" means even though it is defined in the library, which leads me to believe that the process didn't work as expected.

Comment: I don't know either, but I don't see that 'verbatim' error message anywhere.

Comment: My bad, it's actually working correctly. Had a typo. Thanks again!